# Can a Sql Connection remain open if a second using statement exceptions

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

Given the following:

```
try
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (SqlCommand queryCommand = new SqlCommand(QueryString, connection))
        {
            queryCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
 //logging occurs
}
```

If the `.ExecuteScalar()` method throws an exception, will the connection remain open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because you are using the [`using`-statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which ensures that the connection is disposed even in case of an exception. If you want the connection to stay open you have to use a `Try/Catch`:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (SqlCommand queryCommand = new SqlCommand(QueryString, connection))
    {
        try
        {
            queryCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        } catch (Exception ex)
        { 
            // log this exception or do something else useful 
        }
        // now do something else with the command/connection
    }
}
```

Comment: Including when the exception occurs inside the "inner" using statement? I'm attempting to diagnose a problem with a legacy system.

Comment: @RLT: The "inner" using is not related to the `SqlConnection` but only to the `SqlCommand`. So after the `using` of the `SqlCommand` the connection is still open, but as soon as it leaves the scope of the "outer" using the connection will get disposed which also closes it..

Comment: Apologies, I've updated the question to match exactly what's going on in the code, will your above comment still apply?

Comment: @RLT: The surrounding try/catch doesn't matter. `connection` lives from the start of the `using` to the end. An exception will first cause the using block to "end".